# Pacemaker Check if master

Tags: linux, cluster

I have a few shell scripts running while loops and they're extremely expensive because they check to see if the system is master by running "pcs status".  Does anyone else know of a cheaper way of doing this?  Something in proc or maybe /var/lib/pacemaker/?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: crm_mon -1 seems to be the cheapest way to do this.  I read the code in the python for pcs and status.py and that's what it seems to be doing.